# Child div height same as sibling div Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is is possible to have child div same height as parent in bootsrtap 3?

Here  is example

```
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red;">

 VERY LONG TEXT, JUST LONER< AND LONGER, AND LONGER, AND LONGER 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:green;">

SHORT TXT
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want right col to be the same height as left column is that possible on easy way?

Comment: Could you share your CSS? Only thing I can recommand is setting the height of .col-md-6 to 100%

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202769/2-columns-of-equal-height-twitters-bootstrap-2-0?rq=1

Comment: There are numerous solutions to this in CSS and JavaScript. Setting 100% height will not work. Just Google equal height divs...

Comment: Nice can you write solution for this simple example??

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height

Answer (score 6):

here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/2316/

```
.row {overflow: hidden;}
.col-md-6 {
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    }
```

Comment: then use js or simple height: XXpx for each div :)

Comment: "then use js or simple height: XXpx for each div" this is simple css and is not cheat.. is the basic of the css

Comment: I like this very much!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just set a height on both the divs style="height: 100px;"

Comment: If you set only min-height is not necessary both divs to be equal. For example you set min-height:200px; but the div on the left can have 300px and the one from the right can have 300px.

Comment: this solutions is not ideal for a responsive design.